# misconception about pointers C++

Tags: c++, pointers

it seems that i have a misconception about pointers,

here is an example:(code may not compile,is on different PC)

```
#include <iostream>

struct Debris{
    long big_data;
    //code
};

struct Explosion{
    Debris *db;
    //code
};

void test(){
    Debris *db = new Debris();
    db->big_data = 10000;

    Explosion *e1 = new Explosion();

    e1->db = db;

    std::cout << "db addr:" << db <<"db value:"<< ++db->big_data <<<="" "explosion's="" db="" addr:"="" e1-="">db << "explosion's db value:" << e1->db->big_data << std::endl;

    //why db and e1->db have different addresses?
    //but the e1->db->big_data is changed by ref.
}
```

can you please explain this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question seems to be insufficiently precise. Can you explain what exactly you're have trouble understanding?

Comment: Why are you `++`'ing `db`, thus changing the pointer?

Comment: Never mind, turns out that that would only be an issue if you were using the post-increment operator, not the pre-increment. Still looks odd, though.

Comment: Does not compile. What's `<<<=` meant to be?

Comment: <<<= well thats wrong i meant <<

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII i am not changing the pointer but the value pointed.

Comment: what i am trying to say is that while db and e1->db have different addresses the value of e1->db is changed when the value of db changes.How that happens?\

Comment: @yet_another_noob: It's very unclear what you're asking. Could you post real, compilable code, and explain what output you get and why you think it should be different?

Comment: @yet_another_noob: Explain *what*? What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

When I fix the `cout` expression so it compiles, I see:

```
db addr:0x1378010 
db value:10001 
explosion's=0x1378010 
explosion's db value:10000
```

I assume you're asking why the value seems to be different, and you think should be the same in both cases. The pointers are the same, as one would expect since nothing changes them.

This is because you are both modifying and using the value in the same expression, without anything to sequence these actions. This gives the code undefined behaviour; you could see the old value, or the new value, or something completely unexpected could happen.

If you were to break it into two statements, then the first would be sequenced before the second and you would see the same value in each case:

```
std::cout << "db addr:" << db <<" db value:"<< ++db->big_data;
std::cout << " explosion's=" << e1->db << " explosion's db value:" << e1->db->big_data << std::endl;

db addr:0x1720010 
db value:10001 
explosion's=0x1720010 
explosion's db value:10001
```

Answer (score -1):

The fact that you incremented *db* accounts for the change. ++ is high priority among the operators. Add parentheses if your intent was to instead increment big_data before using the value.

Comment: Nope, sorry my comment was wrong. According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) pre-increment has lower precedence than `->`.

Comment: *wrinkles nose* Would you believe that I came up with the same incorrect answer independently? Ah well, that will teach me to post without refreshing the page.